# Should an application ask for iCloud usage permission?

Tags: ios, icloud, user-permissions

When we need to obtain permission to access GPS coordinates, the system does this for us automatically. Similarly with In-App Purchases, the framework automatically confirms does user really want to buy something.

How about iCloud?

I'm developing an application to take photos and I'm thinking about adding iCloud to it.
Why not - it's cool if user can access his/her albums on any device he/she owns. 
But each photo has a big size. 200 photos and 1 Gigabyte is gone.

What is your approach? Do you ask the user in order to use iCloud or local storage, or simply use the iCloud if it's available?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to ask the user.

Since you are storing only user generated content, there is no problem.

Keep in mind that the user can enable/disable iCloud from the system settings, and can disable data storage for applications.
He can also delete user-data, per application.

If you want your users to be able to choose between local storage and iCloud storage, best way, IMHO, is to detect if iCloud is available, using `NSFileManager` methods, and then, if it's on, decide if your app should sync data by default.
I guess this setting should be on by default, as this is the expected behaviour for an iCloud user, but this is up to you

Anyway, don't ask the user about this through an annoying popup. It's very irritating for a first launch, and some users may not understand.
If you need to provide a way to configure this, adds a settings bundle to your app, so the users will be able to configure it.

Comment: it might be necessary to ask the user if values of a third party (e.g. taken from webservices) are stored to the cloud

Answer (score 2):

it looks like apple may have updated their documentation since some of these answers. while i personally think it might be a little jarring to ask (and don't know that I see a ton of apps that do), Apple does recommend doing so in their iCloud Design Guide. They even give you the code for the alert itself:

```
if (currentiCloudToken && firstLaunchWithiCloudAvailable) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
    initWithTitle: @"Choose Storage Option"
          message: @"Should documents be stored in iCloud and available on all your devices?"
         delegate: self
cancelButtonTitle: @"Local Only"
otherButtonTitles: @"Use iCloud", nil];
// and
     [alert show];
}
```

Comment: As a user i find it more jarring to find that app that has been using several megabytes of storage when I haven't granted them permission to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If the user creates or uploads data with your app and expects to see that same data on another iOS or OSX device then using iCloud makes sense.

Using iCloud for app private data, is not recommended since you will use up the users space without approval.

As far as prompting you could ask the user if they want to sync their data, but I find that that can even be more confusing than just syncing by default, since multiple devices may have been working without being synced and users dont understand how your app might handle the merge.

Users can delete files from iCloud in settings if they run out of space.  So its no big deal.

Comment: That's why I ask. In the iCloud programming guide there is no requirement or good practise to ask for user approval. Neither it happens automatically. It's up to us (devs) if we use it or not.

It's not app private data - it's user documents - photos.

Comment: Apple recommends you use iCloud for user documents.  Thats what its designed for.