# How does an app ask the user to login to icloud?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

In an iOS app, how does the app ask/request the user to login to icloud from the app? is there a way without having to instruct them to go out to Settings and return to the app ??

Comment: This should help you out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447299/should-an-application-ask-for-icloud-usage-permission

Comment: that thread discusses the alerting of the user that the app wants to use iCloud. in the app, I am already doing that. I'm hoping to make the app present a "login to icloud" type system modal to get the User to know they were logged out of icloud and need to be logged back into it...